# How print the return Jira API in simple text

Tags: php, jira-rest-api

```
 [description] => {color:#595959}Eresh,{color} 
{color:#595959} {color} 
{color:#595959}Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s{color}  
{color:#595959} {color} 
{color:#595959}Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s{color} 
{color:#595959} {color}
```

The return jira api has color also. I want to print simple description.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this regex to replace content of between curly braces
preg_replace( "/{(.*?)}/" , "" , $description);